# Child elements not expanding html body or parent element

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this fiddle to go with the explanation:
http://jsfiddle.net/Br3jz/1/
I have a background style set on a containing `div`, and I want this background filling the entire screen at all times. I have inner `.containers` that are centered and are at a fixed with of 1064px. The problem arises when the device width is less than 1064px.

When this happens, the containing `div`, as well as the HTML `body` element are both stuck at the original device width. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `#main` doesn't want to have more width than its parent, so it has a fluid width. But `.container` has a fixed width, which can be greater than `#main`'s one. In that case, it overflows.

You have two possible solutions, with different effects:

**Solution 1**: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Br3jz/2/)

Instead of `width: 1064px`, use

```
.container {
    max-width: 1064px;
}
```

**Solution 2**: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Br3jz/3/)

```
.container {
    width: 1064px;
}
#main {
    min-width: 1064px;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that my header is having the same issue - I don't want my navigation, title, and logos all wrapping underneath each other on smaller screens, I want them fixed width and I can handle incremental screen sizes via javascript.

Comment: @Zerkey Try my second solution

Comment: They aren't stuck at original device width. They are *stuck* at the width you set it to. I don't see anything about your header in this question. The answer is `width: 100%; max-width: 1064px;` - http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/KtEoy

Comment: @sheriffderek and Oriol, thanks for your input. I just noticed stackoverflow itself suffers from this problem. Zoom your browser in and scroll to the right, the text overflows the background...

Comment: If you look at the source of this page, the `#content` is set with `width: 980px`  - Pretty much all sites built with absolute numbers are going to have this problem. As far as *background* - the element is the width of the browser window. - when that changes - it doesn't know how to deal with it in certain situations. It's not something you need to fix - just don't build sites like that.